# Byte data from PNG returns incorrect values in C

Tags: arrays, c, image, file, binary

Im trying to read a png without using any external libraries in C, and so far I've managed to retrieve a png's bytes and split them into respective chunks. However, when I try to access any of the data from these chunks, it returns very bad values. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3n2p.png) is my test picture, and it has dimensions 202x71. However, when I try to print the width and height retrieved by my program when it accesses the IHDR chunk, I get:

```
width: -1996594944 - height: -1577759370
```

which physically cant be the pictures dimensions due to them being negative. This is weird, because even if the data is incorrect, my code still seems to be getting the proper types and lengths:

```
value of type: IHDR
value of data: ê■a
value of length: 13
value of crc: FK╪«

value of type: sRGB
value of data: ê■a
value of length: 1
value of crc: «╬Θ
```

I know that printing binary data isn't the best, but its just there because. The function which calculates the chunks is this:

```
typedef struct Chunk Chunk;
struct Chunk {
    int length;
    unsigned char type[4];
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned char crc[4];
};

Chunk* getChunksFromBytes(unsigned char* bytes)
{
    int next_seg = 7;
    int chunks = 0;
    long int size = 1;

    Chunk new_chunk;
    Chunk* file_chunks = (Chunk*) malloc(sizeof(Chunk));
    Chunk* temp = file_chunks;

    while(1){
        new_chunk.length = (int) bytes[next_seg+1] << 24 |
                           bytes[next_seg+2] << 16 |
                           bytes[next_seg+3] << 8 |
                           bytes[next_seg+4];

        new_chunk.type[0] = bytes[next_seg+5];
        new_chunk.type[1] = bytes[next_seg+6];
        new_chunk.type[2] = bytes[next_seg+7];
        new_chunk.type[3] = bytes[next_seg+8];

        unsigned char data[new_chunk.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < new_chunk.length; i++){
            data[i] = bytes[next_seg+9+i];
        }

        new_chunk.data = data;

        new_chunk.crc[0] = bytes[next_seg+new_chunk.length+9];
        new_chunk.crc[1] = bytes[next_seg+new_chunk.length+10];
        new_chunk.crc[2] = bytes[next_seg+new_chunk.length+11];
        new_chunk.crc[3] = bytes[next_seg+new_chunk.length+12];

        size += sizeof(new_chunk)+1;

        temp = realloc(temp, size);
        temp[chunks] = new_chunk;
        chunks++;

        if(bytes[next_seg+5] == 'I' && bytes[next_seg+6] == 'E' && bytes[next_seg+7] == 'N' && bytes[next_seg+8] == 'D') break;
        next_seg+=new_chunk.length+12;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

and the code where I use these values to calculate the height and width are seen here:

```
Chunk* file_chunks = getChunksFromBytes(file_bytes);
int width = (int) file_chunks[0].data[0] << 24 |
                  file_chunks[0].data[1] << 16 |
                  file_chunks[0].data[2] << 8 |
                  file_chunks[0].data[3];
int height = (int) file_chunks[0].data[4] << 24 |
                   file_chunks[0].data[5] << 16 |
                   file_chunks[0].data[6] << 8 |
                   file_chunks[0].data[7];
```

I double checked that the order was right according to [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) entry on png files, yet the dimensions still seem to be incorrect. I don't have any inkling on why this could be. Please do help.

Comment: You are using the contents of array `data` beyond its lifetime. Use `malloc` to allocate the chunk data.

Comment: @IanAbbott 'beyond its lifetime'? I'm not sure I understand, sorry, where would I use `malloc`?

Comment: You would use `malloc` to allocate the memory that `new_chunk.data` points to. The variable `unsigned char data[new_chunk.length];` has _automatic storage duration_. Its lifetime will expire when the end of enclosing block is reached or you leave the enclosing block in some other way. (Looping back to the start of the `while` counts as leaving the previous iteration of the block, even if it starts a new iteration of the block.)